# Customize html datalist dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I want to customize the way datalist drop down shows. I have the following datalist right now

```
<input type="text" id="employee" list="employee">
<datalist id="employee">
    <option value="John Doe">John Doe (ID: 1)</option>
    <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe (ID: 2)</option>
    <option value="John Jane">John Jane (ID: 3)</option>
</datalist>
```

When I type on the input box, I see the output like this
[image]

But my requirement is to make it look like below and

[image]

When the drop down is selected, only the name should be selected (without the id). Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?  Basically I want to show more details in the dropdown but select only the Name and not the Id for submitting the form. Also, I dont want 2 columns (darker and lighter) in the dropdown. I just want the value with more information.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfyop7sw/1/) which I used for this question.

P.S. - I am generating this datalist dynamically from Ajax Call based on the user input in text field. Also, I cannot use jquery to manipulate anything. It has to be native javascript.

Comment: Remove the content between the tags. You can customize the value attribute of each option when you receive the data from the AJAX call. [Take a look at this link.](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element)

Comment: You should post more code, specifically the one generating the datalist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second column is appearing because you are putting content between the opening and closing  tags. **Change:**

```
<option value="John Doe">John Doe (ID: 1)</option>
```

**to:**

```
<option value="John Doe"></option>
```

to remove the second column.

This can be done on receiving the data via the AJAX call, simply, create the option in JavaScript:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = name + " (ID: " + id + ")";
document.getElementById("my-datalist").appendChild(option);
```

The above code will make one column, however, it contains the ID in the value field. You would have to remove that before submitting if you didn't want it submitted with the form. Or you can have two columns one for the name (value attribute) and one for the ID (text content).

For more information, refer to this [link.](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element)

Comment: When you down vote provide a reason as to why. This answers the question efficiently and effectively. If this doesn't answer your question you must provide more code and be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I dont know who down voted your answer. I checked your response just now. I have following questions based on your answer:
1. If I have just value="John Doe", then how will my drop down look like Jone Doe (ID: 1)
2. If I use option.value = name + " (ID: " + id + ")"; combination, how can my submit value be just name ? 
Like I asked before, I want to show more option in the dropdown but submit only partial information from it.

Comment: @Raghuveer you would have to either parse the response before submitting by removing the ID from the value, or you would have to have two columns one for the name and the other for the ID (which I find more aesthetically appealing). It seems there's no way to get exactly what you want (unless you create a custom element) but the closest would be one of the options I provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will parse the response.

Comment: It works. I added a queryselector on input and trimmed the addition value. Thanks !

Comment: @Raghuveer you could post your final solution for others to see.and copy paste?